# componentDidMount or componentWillMount not working in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to fetch cities using API but componentDidMount nor componentWillMount is working.

I have tested my getWeather function using button, the function is working but when I try to call the it using componentDidMount or componentWillMount it is not working...

My code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './Header';
import { TextInput, Card, Button, Title } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function Home() {

    const [info, setInfo] = useState([{
        city_name: "loading !!",
        temp: "loading",
        humidity: "loading",
        desc: "loading",
        icon: "loading"
    }]);

    getWeather = () => {
        console.log("Hello Weather");
        fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&units=metric&appid={MY_API_KEY}")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            /*setInfo([{
                city_name: data.name,
                temp: data.main.temp,
                humidity: data.main.humidity,
                desc: data.weather[0].description,
                icon: data.weather[0].icon}]);
                */
        })
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        console.log("Hello Will");
        this.getWeather();
    }
    
    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log("Hello Did");
        this.getWeather();
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Header title="Current Weather"/>
          <Card style = {{margin: 20}}>
              <View>
                  <Title>{info.city_name}</Title>
                  <Title>{info.desc}</Title>
              </View>
          </Card>
          <Button onPress={() => this.getWeather()} style={{margin: 40, padding: 20}}>Testing</Button>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount` only work in class based React components; what you have here is a functional component.  You can use the `useEffect` hook to accomplish the same.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getWeather();
}, []);
```

Note that `this` does not exist in functional components; you can just call the function directly after you have declared it.

If you haven't used `useEffect` before, you may have questions about the array as the second argument.  If it is empty, it will run on mount and will run what you return from the first argument on unmount.  If you want to run your effect again, add an dependencies into the array.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Can you tell me more about in your answer i.e. regarding the second arguement in array

Comment: Check out the [React docs for useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) for further reading.  If you have a prop called `users` that may change and you want to run your effect every time it changes, you can add `[users]` as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount would only work in class components. Using the useEffect React hook would achieve the same effect without issues